# asp.net html page retrieval

Tags: asp.net

How to Get the Content In the Body section of a HTML page in asp.net

like

> this is content

i just want the content 'this is content'..

and how to find all Images and .swf file in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use StreamReader to read the content from file and then Use RegEx to split it and get the desired part.